# How to plot a stem graph with multiple colors depending on the interval

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, matlab-stem

Suppose you have a Matlab function which is defined over an interval [0:3*period], is there a way to produce a stem graph so that each period will have different colored stems?

Here's a bit of code so you can see what I mean:

```
T = 36;
n = [ 0 : 3 * T ];
x1 = cos( 5 * pi * n / 6 );
x2 = cos( 4 * pi * n / 9 );
z = x1 + x2;
```

Now I want to plot z(n) with a stem graph over three periods, but each period has to be a different color ( [ 0 : T ] in blue, [ T : 2T ] in red, and [ 2T : 3T ] in green ). Is there a way to specify the color of the stem graph depending on the interval of the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by splitting data into three separate groups based on the reference period ([logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)) and, subsequently, by plotting a separate stem for every group on the same axis ([hold approach](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)):

```
% Build data...
T = 36;
n = 1:(3*T);
z = cos(5 * pi() * n / 6) + cos(4 * pi() * n / 9);

% Define the splitting indices...
idx1 = n <= T;
idx2 = (n > T) & (n <= 2*T);
idx3 = (n > 2*T) & (n <= 3*T);

% Plot the data groups into the current axis...
stem(n(idx1),z(idx1),'fill','-b');
hold on;
stem(n(idx2),z(idx2),'fill','-r');
stem(n(idx3),z(idx3),'fill','-g');
hold off;
```

Here is the final result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.